# php proc_open 'su: must be run from a terminal'

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu-12.04, proc-open

I have this PHP code in a personal Ubuntu Server machine:

```
    $cmd = 'su testuser';
    $descriptorspec = array(
        array('pipe', 'r'),
        array('pipe', 'w'),
        array('pipe', 'w')
    );
    $pipes = array();
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'password\r');
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $string = array(stream_get_contents($pipes[1]), stream_get_contents($pipes[2]));
    proc_close($process);
    echo exec('whoami') . "\n";
    print_r($string);
```

And I get from PHP this response:

```
www-data
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => su: must be run from a terminal

)
```

It's obvious I want to change the active user but is there any way to do this from php?

Comment: If you want to run a specific command or script, either use `sudo` or set the `sticky bit`. But be careful with this on scripts, as they might get interrupted and you still have the underlying interpreter / shell + environment + environment variables.

Comment: You can't change the active user of the current process, you can only switch to another user in a _new_ process. If you `su` in bash, you can see what it actually does with `ps f`: it's a brand new shell. Likewise, you can't change the process php runs as, but you _may_ be able to start a subprocess one (although I'd normally avoid that in a webserver). Depending on your need for another user, packages like `suphp`, or using `SuExec` could be possible solutions to your problem. Another option is running a deamon like gearmand with the correct user, which obeys requests from www-data.

Answer (score 1):

The su command will only change the current user while the bash shell it was executing in is still running. Even if you were to do $cmd = **'bash -c "sudo su testuser"'** (which will execute as intended) you would only change the current user until you execute proc_close, so the exec('whoami') will always give you the username of the user who originally lauched your php script.  But you can use the command in bold to execute a bash shell that will execute as testuser and then pipe commands to it. For instance if you pipe 'whoami' instead of 'nirvana3105\r' whoami should return 'testuser'.  Hope that helps.

Try this code(replacing password with your password):

```
<?php
    $cmd = "sudo -S su testuser";

    echo $cmd;

    $desc = array(array('pipe', 'r'), array('pipe', 'w'), array('pipe', 'w'));
    $pipes = array();

    $process = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], "password\n");
    fwrite($pipes[0], "whoami");
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $string = array(stream_get_contents($pipes[1]), stream_get_contents($pipes[2]));
proc_close($process);

    print_r($string);
 ?>
```

Comment: This code worked when I ran it in from the terminal.  Since in your above question the whoami returned www-data I assume you are running it through apache?  If so you need to add the www-data to the sudo group using "sudo adduser www-data sudo".  Note, however, that this is probably not recommended because you don't want the apache web user to have this kind of authority.  If this is just for a local intranet site you have or something like that it should be fine otherwise this poses a bit of a security threat to your system.